# How to prevent iOS app from caching any data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem. My iOS app was under penetration test and the testers tell me that the app is caching user login data. How I can prevent from this. Is this a functionality that can be disabled.

Comment: Where are you storing data in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the application does not store or cache data by itself, please check if you are using a 3rd party library for login credentials that may store login information without your consent.

Moreover, please check the HTTP call mechanism, the request may cache the response per URL (CachePolicy) option.

Comment: Normally an app does! [`.useProtocolCachePolicy
`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/useprotocolcachepolicy) is the **default** cachePolicy. So by default URLs are cached. If server sends `cache-control` headers that allow caching then problems like this will rise. <— Server team screwup —— Client team screw up —> Additionally app can use [`.returnCacheDataDontLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/returncachedatadontload) for a URL or session which will then cache regardless of what servers tells it to.